# Android updates for Nexus bought from Amazon

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Is there any difference in terms of either phone features, software versions or time to get new updates if I bought the [Galaxy Nexus from Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Galaxy-Nexus-16GB-Free-Smartphone/dp/B005XYU45E) instead of waiting for it to be sold direct from Google in the UK?

Any reasons I should wait?

Answer (score 4):

Galaxy Nexus goes by variants such as yakju, yakjuxw, and takju. However yakju and takju will receive updates directly from Google. While the rest will be receiving from Samsung or probably network provider.

The difference between yakju and takju is that takju has Google wallet while yakju does not. Takju can only be purchased from Play Store.

I assume the one being sold directly from Google in the UK is the same one offered at Play Store which runs takju while the one on Amazon runs yakju.

In term of phone hardware they are exactly the same.

Comment: Where can you see those model codes? Nothing like that shows up under "About Phone" as far as I can see?

Comment: Thanks. So in theory the Amazon one is better with support for the wallet? Is it as unlocked as the one from Google. Yes I'm talking about the one from the play store btw.

Comment: @GAThrawn There are two ways you can do it: 
<br />
1. By viewing build.prop.
2. Or the easier way by using [GN Official Update Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cbruegg.officialupdate)

Comment: @Adam I won't say that it's better just because it has Wallet. As I don't find much usage for Wallet since it is not supported in my country. I'm not sure if it is unlocked thou. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, in the end found it this moprning in [Android System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi), under **System** -> **Build Info**. Contrary to what you've said though, my Galaxy Nexus bought through my provider in the UK, with no Wallet support, is a YAKJU.

Comment: It seems like it's the same case with me. There is no Wallet although it's Yakju. I guess Yakju with Wallet only available in the US.

Comment: After further reading I discover that I had it wrong. Takju has Wallet while Yakju doesn't. Sorry for providing incorrect information.